# weyl asymptotic formula

Tags: limits

I'm having trouble to evaluate a limit (shame on me!). It has to do with Weyl's asymptotic formula. It goes roughly as follows: $\Omega \subseteq M^n$. So the eigenvalues of the dirichlet laplacian satisfy

\begin{equation}
 \lim_{l \to \infty} \frac{\lambda_l}{l^{\frac{2}{n}}} = \frac{4\pi^2}{(\omega_n |\Omega|)^{\frac{2}{n}}}
\end{equation}

Now I should be able to conclude that

\begin{equation}
  \lim_{l \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{l}\sum\limits_{i=1}^l\lambda_i}{l^{\frac{2}{n}}} = \frac{n}{n+2}\frac{4\pi^2}{(\omega_n |\Omega|)^{\frac{2}{n}}}
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want $$\lim \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{l}\lambda _i}{l^{1+2/n}}.$$ 
Use [discrete L'Hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Statement_of_the_Theorem_.28the_.E2.88.99.2F.E2.88.9E_case.29).

Compute instead the limit of the quotients of the discrete derivatives

\begin{align}\lim \frac{\lambda_l}{(l+1)^{1+2/n}-l^{1+2/n}}&=\lim \frac{\lambda_l}{l^{2/n}}\lim \frac{l^{2/n}}{(l+1)^{1+2/n}-l^{1+2/n}}\\&=\lim \frac{\lambda_l}{l^{2/n}}\lim \frac{1}{(l+1)(1+1/l)^{2/n}-l}\\&=\lim \frac{\lambda_l}{l^{2/n}}\lim \frac{1}{\sum_k\binom{2/n}{k}l^{-k}+\sum_k\binom{2/n}{k}l^{-k+1}-l}\\&=\lim \frac{\lambda_l}{l^{2/n}}\lim\frac{1}{1+\binom{2/n}{1}}\\&=\lim \frac{\lambda_l}{l^{2/n}}\frac{n}{n+2}\end{align}

Since this limit exists (because the given limit exists) then that's the value of the limit you were looking for.

Comment: I don't understand your insistance on omitting the limit specification $l\to \infty$.  Surely this will confuse many Readers.

Comment: @user463383 thanks. it was really helpful. :)